# Windows Phone 8.1 - Max WriteableBitmap size

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app, I need to work with WriteableBitmaps. I want to do the following: if the image doesn't exceed the memory limit, load it entire, but if it exceeds it, load a scaled-down version instead.
So, what's the limit of size of images when using a WriteableBitmap?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a guess, but I'd say it's limited by your phone's memory.
On a 512MB device you probably only have a few dozen MB of memory for a WB, so 4 bytes (ARGB) per pixel yields say 10M pixels so something like 2500x4000 pixels assuming you use almost no significant amounts of memory for anything else.